# Git: how to accept "theirs" version of a submodule conflict?

Tags: git, conflict, git-submodules

In case of a submodule conflict (i.e. when the two commits to merge contain different changes of the referenced commit), how can I easily set the submodule to "theirs" commit? In case of files, I would perform:

```
git checkout --theirs <file>
```

However this does not work for submodules. On a more technical level, what I have is an Index containing the `submodule` for stages *1*, *2* and *3*:

```
$ git ls-files -s module
160000 89b085c4269259fa22632353071e6875f158afde 1       submodule
160000 b9ad3bc8aafdf52a2adf74620afae8934474b82d 2       submodule
160000 1afd42893d18ef5edeeadd67e7c65262505e6004 3       submodule
```

and what I want is to have the "theirs" version in stage *0*:

```
$ git ls-files -s module
160000 1afd42893d18ef5edeeadd67e7c65262505e6004 0       submodule
```

**Update:** false assertion on reference http://fiji.sc/wiki/index.php/Git_submodule_tutorial removed.

**Update 2:** Index-related example added.

Comment: Did you try to execute `git checkout --theirs` from inside the submodule folder?

Comment: No, from the parent repository folder.

Comment: The submodules are independent repositories. There are specific commands to deal with them.

Comment: I don't want to touch the submodule repository, I only want to make the parent's repository "submodule pointer" point to "theirs" instead of "ours" commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parent repository just refers to the current working version of your submodule repository. The "submodule pointer" always points to the working copy of the submodule.

So you have to put the submodule repository in the state you want to (in this specific case, by updating it to "theirs" version). After that, the "submodule pointer" will update itself automatically (of course, you'll have to commit the change).

Comment: So there is no (easy) way to turn stage 3 to stage 0 in my parent repository, without touching the submodule?

Comment: @mstrap You want your parent repository working copy to reference "stage 0", while the submodule working copy is at "stage 3"? Why would you want this? How are you thinking your working copy of the parent repository should work - should it use "stage 0" (as referenced by git) or "stage 3" (the actual files in the working copy)?

Comment: for the example above, I want to have "1afd42893d18ef5edeeadd67e7c65262505e6004" in stage 0 and stage 1-3 removed, so the state of the submodule will turn from "conflicted" to "modified".

Comment: Once again, the submodule reference in your parent repository corresponds to your working copy of the submodule. Either both your submodule working copy and submodule reference in parent repositorty are "1afdwhatever" or both are "stage3". If you want to rollback recent changes in the submodule (so that the parent repository will refer to some earlier submodule version), rollback your working copy of the submodule first. I don't get why're you so opposed to changing the working copy of the submodule.

Comment: I disagree: the parent repository stores the referenced submodule commit as separate piece of information. This reference can be different from the actual submodule HEAD. Still you may be right, that there is no way to change the reference in the parent repository without touching the submodule itself (to be able to perform a simple "git add module").

Comment: "This reference can be different from the actual submodule HEAD." - I'm not talking about **HEAD**, I'm talking about your **working copy** (which can be different from the actual submodule HEAD). You have to touch the working copy of the submodule itself; but, of course, you don't have to touch the submodule repository.

Comment: In your answer you suggest to "put the submodule repository in the state you want to". This is what I want to avoid. I thought there might be some low-level Git command to just manipulate the my parent repository .git/index file to yield desired result. Probably there is none.

Comment: It seems that I've just wrongly expressed myself. You need to put the submodule **working copy** in the state you want to (that is, to switch your local repository version to the one you want to). For example, if your version of submodule is tagged as `b`, and you want your parent repository to refer to `a`, you have to do `cd submodule_directory; git checkout a; cd parent_directory; git add submodule_directory; git commit`. Note that no commits to the submodule repository occurs here.